# Does ejecting to ExpoKit reduce standalone app size?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have built my project with Expo but I need to reduce the standalone app size now.
I want to know if I eject to ExpoKit the app size would be reduced or not?

Answer (score 0):

No it will not reduce the standalone app size

Comment: Can you provide a link to documentation?